# New Laravel routes showing XAMPP 404 error

Tags: php, laravel, routes, xampp, laravel-8

I seem to have the problem since today when I wanted to add a new route to a project I have been working on for the past months where XAMPP shows me 404 errors.

I have tried looking everywhere, reinstalled XAMPP, reinstalled my project from github.
The route actually works on other people's computers on the same branch in my repo. making a new route in another project also works.

It's just that in this project XAMPP has decided to take over the error handling from Laravel and give me 404 errors on all new routes I make?
I just can't get into the controller or do anything with the route. I tried changing the route into anything and everything I could think of or find.

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.47 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1k PHP/8.0.6 Server at 360feedback.hz.nl Port 443
```

*edit: I am using VirtualHost, which has always worked without issues.
every existing route works fine, route:clear does nothing.

Does anyone know what could cause this?

Another edit as i have found out some more things.
So this problem only occurs on my one project. Which makes things even stranger.

I have also found out that the problem so far seems to be fixed if I use the IP from xampp instead of using a custom domain I added in windows hosts

[this picture shows the error on the one with domain and no error without domain.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dFA0p.png)

also here is my vhost config

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.3:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/davye/Documents/GitHub/SchoolProject-1/public"
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    ServerName laravel-gkb.test
    <Directory "C:/Users/davye/Documents/GitHub/SchoolProject-1/public">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Order Deny,Allow
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing the route cache or caching the routes? `php artisan route:clear`/`php artisan route:cache` respectively.  Also, do they show up when you run the command `php artisan route:list --columns=uri,action` ?

Comment: This 404 error is **not belongs** to laravel, it raises from your **apache server**

Comment: I have, for us it has been a bit annoying but we have to route:clear after every change in the web.php

Comment: They also show up in route:list and are not being blocked by similar routes. like i said on other people's pc's the exact code works. It just doesn't on mine

Comment: You shouldn't have to `route:clear` every time. `route:clear` only clears cached routes. Unless someone runs `route:cache` (which creates the `bootstrap/cache/routes.php` file that should NOT be commited), there are no routes to cache.

Comment: But I'm not knowledgeable in apache configuration so I can't help you with your problem.

Comment: Bummer, well thanks for trying anyway. (I’ll look into the route clearing another time)

Comment: Can you post here the virtualhost config?

Comment: I posted it in an edit

Comment: Your ServerName in vHost is "laravel-gkb.test" not "360feedback.hz.nl" also try to set the virtualhost "<VirtualHost *:80>"@JustDave